# How to send VisualFlow email using dynamic sender address from sites visualpage?

Tags: email, force.com-sites, flow, guest-user

I have a visual flow that needs to send an email to the account contact, using the account contact's owner details.

The flow is invoked from a force sites guest user.

-- **Test flow** --

[image]

I have tried to use the `orgwideaddress`, but I don't think it's correct. I don't want to give all profile users ability to send as any other profile user. 
- And trying to limit that to the `sites guest user` is not listed in the list of profiles.

- I want to have the flow get as input an email address, and use that as the sender.

Is it possible?

Comment: OrgWideEmailAddress is obviously not a Sender Type. It would seem that you'd need to set that to something like Owner, User, Contact, Admin, etc. I don't believe you can assign the sites guest user send email permissions or flow user permissions for that matter, but could be mistaken. Thus the reason this is a comment since I don't have time to search & check right now.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_action_email_flow.htm&language=en_US) your options for sender are limited to:

CurrentUser—Email address of the user running the flow. (Default). (this should be the email address of the site guest user, though I'm not sure if that can be customized or not)

DefaultWorkflowUser—Email address of the default workflow user.

OrgWideEmailAddress—The organization-wide email address that is specified in Sender Address.

You do not have the option to specify the sender manually.  You can merge in owner info to the body, but not as the sender.

Org wide addresses would not work for your requirement, as they are one address (eg info@yourorg.com).  It would not be dynamically defined.

You could specify sender w apex email message.

Another option might be to look at a mass email tool, I've seen ones that provide option to send as record owner.

Hope that helps.